# How can I use XlsxWriter or other external libraries with PythonKit?

Tags: python, swift, xcode, xlsxwriter, swift-pythonkit

I've been trying to use my XlsxWriter based python script in my swift app with PythonKit.

At first I tried installing XlsxWriter by running:

pip3 install XlsxWriter

It installed with no errors and the code runs fine in PyCharm when I import the library into the project. This however is broken in Swift.

My swift is:

```
import Foundation
import PythonKit


let dirPath = "/Users/johnson/Desktop/"

func runPythonCode(){
    let sys = Python.import("sys")
    sys.path.append(dirPath)
    let example = Python.import("sample")
    let response = example.hello()
    print(response)
}

runPythonCode()
```

My python is:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 'Heyeyeye')

workbook.close()
```

Xcode returns the following error when I try to run:

```
PythonKit/Python.swift:706: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Python exception: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
Traceback:
  File "/Users/johnson/Desktop/sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xlsxwriter

2022-12-08 11:09:52.812915+0200 Python-Test[21898:534512] PythonKit/Python.swift:706: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Python exception: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
Traceback:
  File "/Users/johnson/Desktop/sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xlsxwriter
```

Partial solution:

Running:

```
pip install XlsxWriter
```

instead of:

```
pip3 install XlsxWriter
```

fixes this within Xcode.

Remaining issue:

When I export my executable via:

Xcode>Product>Archive>Distribute Content>Built Products

The executable runs the swift code fine, manages to import the python file but returns the following error:

```
PythonKit/Python.swift:706: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Python exception: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

The code runs fine within Xcode, no problems with xlsxwriter, but the standalone executable running the same python script fails. What could be causing this?

Comment: There is also a C version of xlsxwriter, called libxlsxwriter, that you can [use directly in Swift via CocoaPod](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/getting_started.html#gsg_cocoapods) or via the [Swift wrapper](https://swiftpackageregistry.com/damuellen/xlsxwriter.swift).

Comment: @jmcnamara, thank you! I'll definitely keep that in mind if I have to write something like that again. I just want to get this project integrated and done though.